# Show $|f(0)| \le e$ for holomorphic function satisfying $ |f(e^{i\pi t})|\leq e^{t}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a holomorphic function on the closed unit disk such that :
$$ | f(e^{i\pi t})| \leq e^{t}, \forall t \in [0,2] \, .$$

Show that $$ | f(0)| \leq e \, .$$

I tried to use this relation to use the average value of $f$ in $0$
$$ f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})dt= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}f(e^{i\pi t})dt$$
so $$ | f(0)| \leq \frac{e^2-1}{2}$$ which is far from the desired inequality.

Comment: Maximum modulus on the unit disc

Comment: @Conrad:the upper bound I am looking for is e according to the exercise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function
$$
 g(z) = f(z) \cdot \overline{f(\bar z)} 
$$
is holomorphic in the closed unit disk and satisfies
$$
|g(e^{i\pi t})| =  |f(e^{i\pi t})| \cdot |f(e^{i\pi (2-t)})| \le e^t \cdot e^{2-t} = e^2 \, .
$$
for $0 \le t \le 2$. The maximum modulus principle then gives
$$
 |f(0)|^2 = |g(0)| \le e^2 \, .
$$

*Alternatively* one can use that [$\log|f(z)|$ is subharmonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531138/42969) and therefore satisfies the mean-value inequality
$$
 \log |f(0)| \le \frac 12 \int_0^2 \log |f(e^{i\pi t})| \, dt
\le \frac 12 \int_0^2 t \, dt = 1 \, .
$$

The same estimate also follows from [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula).